# Inheritance in rails engine that is inside a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a functional rails project that already is very complex. We have a request for another sub app that should be absolutely separate from the rails project except for a few models that should be pretty much the same. I set up the engine, mounted the routes, it is working very well and as desired. However, when it comes to testing, I have no idea how to do it as I cannot even generate rspec dummy as I constantly have problems with dependencies from the original rails app, especially on the User model - as I inherited it from the rails app.

```
require_dependency "../../../app/models/user"

module VendingApp
  class User < ::User
    ...
  end
end
```

Is there a way how to require all dependencies from the rails app or how would you handle it if you need to inherit and test it - as the models are really defined in the rails app including its gems and dependencies such as devise, ...

Maybe load the whole rails app + engine as a dummy? But how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't require the models from the first app. Create a different User model instead, which references the same database, as a clone of the User model in the parent app, or create a gem which both apps use.

When you're working with multiple services with the same model, it's OK to have code duplication in order to not couple your services together. Having one service that "inherits" is another way of saying "I'm coupling my service A to B". The fact that you can't test your service A is simply a smell of a bad design decision.

If you want to be even MORE elegant, you can use Plain Ruby Objects to define your Models, and then use an Adapter/Repository class to load them from ActiveRecord. This is a DDD inspired approach, you could see an example on this repository https://github.com/paulrayner/ddd_sample_app_ruby

Comment: Thanks, will have a look!